# Splitting by " | " not between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split a string, but ignoring stuff between square brackets.
You can imagine this akin to ignoring stuff within quotes.

I came across a solution for quotes;

`(\|)(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)`

So;

`one|two"ignore|ignore"|three`

would be;

```
one
two"ignore|ignore"
three
```

However, I am struggling to adapt this to ignore [] instead of ".
Partly its down to there being two characters, not one. Partly its down to [] needing to be escaped, and partly its down to me being pretty absolutely awful at regexs.

My goal is to get;

So;

`one|two[ignore|ignore]|three`

split to;

```
 one
 two[ignore|ignore]
 three
```

I tried figuring it out myself but I got into a right mess;
`(\|)(?=(?:[^\[|\]]|\|][^\[|\]]*\[|\])*$)`
I am seeing brackets and lines everywhere now.

Help!

Comment: Im a little nieve.  Ever think of replacing the "|" inside of all braces with a TMP_CHAR and then do a regex on | and finally replace TMP_CHAR with "|"..   As an alternative, the TMP_CHAR could just be encoded version of "|" to decode moments later.

Comment: Honestly, that isnt a bad idea at all.
I am trying Casimirs solution at the mo, but I might try that next.
Its only half the solution mind - as I need to deal with "[" and "]" as well. Guess I could always use Temp characters for those as well.

Comment: i know you could do stuff like: encodeURIComponent to encode [,],|, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the adapted version of the `""` regex you posted:

```
(\|)(?=(?:[^\]]|\[[^\]]*\])*$)
(\|)(?=(?:[^ "]| "[^ "]* ")*$) <- "" version for comparison
```

You replace the 2nd `"` with `\[` and the 1st and 3rd with `\]`

[Working on RegExr](http://regexr.com?37bvr)

Comment: Thanks, this works as a drop in solution and actually helps show how the original one worked too.

Comment: @darkflame It's also quite simple to simply create a function for you needs, especially if the splitting logic gets more complicated than this. http://pastebin.mozilla.org/3670820

Answer (score 0):

with the split method you can use this pattern since the capturing group is displayed with results:

```
\|((?:[^[|]+|\[[^\]]+])*)\|
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use `String#match`:

```
s='one|two[ignore|ignore]|three';
m = s.match(/[^|\[]+\[.*?\]|[^|]+/g);
//=> ["one", "two[ignore|ignore]", "three"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
"one|two[ignore|ignore]|three".split( /\|(?![^\[]*\])/ )
```

It uses *negative lookahead*, unfortunately *lookbehind* is not supported in JS.